# Await inside Foreach Giving Error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I was having a JS develop in Express JS and we are migrating the application to Typescript for TypeOrm.

```
async function loadRootMessagesForTwitter(req, res) 
{
 const messageRepository = getManager().getRepository(Message);
 req.body.forEach(function(obj) {
  const requestMessage = messageRepository.create(obj);
    var channel_message_ID = requestMessage['channel_message_ID'];
    if (channel_message_ID) {                      
           await messageRepository.save(requestMessage);
        }
     }
```

And i am facing the below Error

```
error TS1308: 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function
```

Comment: forEach contains another function which is not async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function passed to `forEach` would have to be `async`:

```
req.body.forEach(async function(obj) {
  // ...
  await messageRepository.save(requestMessage);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy...But can you please explain why it need to be called inside async and what benefits we are getting...I recently has started working on typescript.

Comment: That turns the callback into something which will return a `Promise`, but there's nothing there to make each iteration of the loop wait until the `save()` call has completed. You would get the same effect simply removing both `await` and `async` here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
async function loadRootMessagesForTwitter(req, res) {
 const messageRepository = getManager().getRepository(Message);
 const arr = req.body;
 for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  let obj = arr[i]
  const requestMessage = messageRepository.create(obj);
  let channel_message_ID = requestMessage['channel_message_ID'];
  if (channel_message_ID) {                      
    await messageRepository.save(requestMessage);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `forEach` with an async callback doesn't work if you want to ensure you wait for each `save()` call to complete before doing the next iteration of the loop. That may not matter in this case as you're ignoring any result of the `save()` call, perhaps you can just throw out a bunch of calls to `save()` and in that case simply:

```
 const messageRepository = getManager().getRepository(Message);
 req.body.forEach(function(obj) {
  const requestMessage = messageRepository.create(obj);
    var channel_message_ID = requestMessage['channel_message_ID'];
    if (channel_message_ID) {                      
           messageRepository.save(requestMessage);
        }
     }
```

However, if you want to control the calls then just stop using `forEach` and use typescript's `for...of` instead:

```
 const messageRepository = getManager().getRepository(Message);
 for (let obj of req.body) {
  const requestMessage = messageRepository.create(obj);
    var channel_message_ID = requestMessage['channel_message_ID'];
    if (channel_message_ID) {                      
           await messageRepository.save(requestMessage);
    }
  }
 }
```